# svn add modified content in a directory without cd

Tags: bash, svn, cygwin

So here is the problem I'm trying to solve in windows, cygwin, using TortoiseSVN:

I have a directory "dir1", which is internal for a directory "dir" which is in subversion control. I have a script that changes the content of "dir1", and I want that script automatically to submit the changes to svn. However running:

```
svn add dir1/*
```

gives me an error:

> svn: E155007:
>   'dir1' is not a working copy.

Now if I use cd dir1, and run

```
svn add *
```

it's working correctly. Is there a way to do that without calling cd?

Comment: So I found out that the problem lays in using a cygwin path: /cygdrive/e/dir1/*, when I use e:/dir1/* it's working. So the new question is how to get the windows path from the cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about altering the current directory of the script you can just run it on a subshell:

```
(cd dir1 && svn add *)
```

The current directory of the calling shell won't be altered by it.

Also you can use pushd and popd but I find using a subshell cleaner:

```
pushd dir1 >/dev/null && { svn add *; popd >/dev/null; }
```

Finally I don't recommend `cd x; cd -`.

Comment: I know how I can do it with cd. But my question is how to do it without switching the directory twice.

Comment: @lalamer With subshells you only switch directories once. At first glance at [svn's options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw) I doubt `svn` supports having a custom base directory for its commands.

Comment: You switch the directories once, but you use a subshell, which causes more overheat than cd. I have found out that the problem is that cygwin is passing the cygwin path e.g. /cygdrive/c... instead of c:/... So if you know a very easy (one line) way to covert the cygwin path to a regular windows path I'll give you acceptance ;). The hard way using string manipulations is not of interest for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see `svn` having support to manipulate files from custom directories. You can do it in `git` with `-C` but not in `svn`. And since that's the case your solution would be to use a subshell, or use other methods that I recommended. See `pushd`.